# java soap webservice xml to object

Tags: java, web-services, soap

i have to write a simple soap webservice, which takes it's XML parameter input and calls a database stored procedure with that XML parameter. The stored procedure returns XML (same XSD), and i have to return this result-XML to the webservice caller.

What is the easiest way to produce the result XML in java? Do i have to make java objects out of the result of the stored procedure (if so, whats the easiest way?) or can i somehow put that resulting XML directly in the response of the webservice. As of now i don't need to check the result for validity.

So far i created the wsdl, generated java classes from the xsd, and created the procedures of the webservice. i test them with SoapUI, they call the database stored procedure and i'm not sure how to handle the XML result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for binding XML schema to java class and vice versa you can use [***JAXB***](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnazf.html). and yes, you can send xml as your response directly. you should set your response content type to xml:

```
response.setContentType("text/xml");
```

Comment: i got some other urgent stuff to do and cant finish this right now, but from a quick glance, JAXB seems the way to go - thanks.